# Are sardines I order in Winter farmed?

Tags: fish, organic, portuguese-cuisine, sardines

In Portugal and Spain, there are quite strict quota regulations limiting fishing to late Spring, Summer and early Autumn: [quota regulations for sardines](https://oceans-and-fisheries.ec.europa.eu/fisheries/rules/fishing-quotas_en). Those quotas regulate the fishing of "free range" sardines.

However, some restaurants in Portugal offer sardines also in the Winter. Where would those sardines come from? Since frozen sardines taste quite differently — badly, in my opinion — compared to fresh ones, could those stocks come from farmed sardines (aquaculture)?

Comment: I was in Lisbon around New Year a few years back and plenty of fresh sardines on the menus. But those could have been frozen or from farther away like south America.